# Python Syntax error makes no sense

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just written a simple Python class to create a list of lists (which will be a tic tac toe board), and it is giving me a syntax error.

I have compared the syntax to a number of other classes, all of which work, and all of which have the same syntax (from what I can see).

This is Python 3.2. The error occurs at the second colon of the code, so after the constructor declarations (or at lease that's whats highlighted in red).

```
class Board:
    def__init__(self, N):
        """Create a list of lists that will represent my playing board"""
        self._N = N
        Brd = []
        for i in range(N):
            Brd = Brd + ['()','()','()']
        self._theBoard = Brd

    def drawBoard(N):
        """Draws the Board"""
        print(self._theBoard)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For future reference: *always* include the full traceback in your post, so we don't have to *guess* at your error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a space between `def` and `__init__`:

```
def__init__(self, N):
```

Add that in:

```
def __init__(self, N):
```

Note that your `drawBoard(N)` method is missing the `self` argument; `N` will be set to the instance instead when called.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you meant `drawBoard` to be a method in your `Board` class, in this case you need to pass `self` to it explicitly:

```
def drawBoard(self, N):
    """Draws the Board"""
    print(self._theBoard)
```

and it should be indented the same way as the other method. Note, that the `N` parameter is useless here.

Others already pointed missing space after `def` in your `__init__` method definition.

Comment: Not the source of the current problem, but a good point.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to give a space here:

```
def__init__(self, N):
```

should be

```
def __init__(self, N):
```

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is the way to define constructor in python. You have to precede it by `def` to declare it is a function. Hence the correct way to do so is:

```
def __init__():
```

That is put space between def and **init**.